# How to accept string of both upper and lower cases in Python

Tags: python, string

My problem here is that I want to take the input in both the capitals and the lower case also if possible in the title form, where the first character is capitalized only. Now in the code given below, when I enter te input as "White" instead of 'white' it updates the 'other' section, I know this is correct because the string doesn't match the case of what I have on the list, but how can I accept both the forms?

```
class myclass:
    sample=0
    white=0
    black=0
    gray=0
    others=0
    colorlist=["white", "black", "gray"]
    def __init__(self):
        print("what is your name?")
        myclass.name=input()
        print("What is the color of your car?")
        myclass.color= input()
        myclass.sample=myclass.sample+1
    def check_color(self):
            if myclass.color in myclass.colorlist:
            if myclass.color == myclass.colorlist[0]:
                myclass.white= myclass.white+1
            elif myclass.color == myclass.colorlist[1]:
                myclass.black=myclass.black+1
            else:
                myclass.gray = myclass.gray+1
        else:
           myclass.others=myclass.others+1
    def display_result(self):
        print ("Hello," ,myclass.name)
        print ("The number of white cars are:", myclass.white)
        print ("The number of black cars are:", myclass.black)
        print ("The number of gray cars are:", myclass.gray)
        print ("The number of other colored cars are:", myclass.others)
        print ("The number samples are:", myclass.sample)
var=0
mylist=[]
while var<4:
    mylist.append(myclass())
    mylist[var].check_color()
    mylist[var].display_result()
    var=var+1
```

Comment: `myclass.color= input().lower()` should be enough: it wil convert color to lowercase right from the user input.

Comment: by default, `convert all strings to either lower case or upper case, then perform comparison`

Comment: IT worked!! Thank you, I was using the capitalize() function. Thank you again. I am relatively new to this so had this silly question.

Comment: @ankurgadgilwar `capitalize()` only converts the first letter of the string to uppercase, for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

This solution only works with Python 3. Python 2 needs a `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

---

```
while True:

    user_input = input("Enter a word: ")

    needed_string = "blue"

    if(user_input.lower() == needed_string):

        print("It works")
```